# How can I test a Rails app using WGET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wget

I want to test my rails app using "wget", specifically the part that returns JSON-data. I don't really understand the syntax I should use. I have tried this:

```
wget --user=username@example.com --password=somepass localhost:3000/folders/1.json
```

and variations of it, without any success. Which is the exact syntax? Would it be better to use CURL instead?

-- edit --

I found at this blog:

```
http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/research/testing-rest-the-hard-way
```

this suggestion:

```
$ wget -S -q --header "Accept: application/json" -O - http://localhost:3000/folders/1
```

but even when I add

```
--user=username@example.com --password=somepass
```

...I get 401 Unauthorised. The username is correct, I can login via the browser.

Comment: There's already an answer with curl below but if you want to look at better read able response then there are many Rest Clients you can use as Chrome  Extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: For the 401 error why not user the other syntax for basic auth (http://username:password@localhost:3000/folders/1)

Answer (score 0):

`curl -u username:password http://localhost:3000/folders/1.json`

Read more here http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u

Comment: curl -u username@example.com:somepass http://localhost:3000/folders/1.json
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."} I'm using Devise and the username/pass is valid

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `curl` is the less well known but equally capable `httpie` - https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie - I find it to be a bit more straightforward and friendly to use, and includes syntax colouring for output.

`http -a user:pass :3030/folders/1.json` would do the trick here, I think.